# Need help returning object in thread run method

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, return

I have a Java class that extends `Thread`, it basically looks like the following:

```
public class HttpRequestDispatcher extends Thread {
    private String url;
    private String method; // GET or POST
    private byte[] postData;

    public HttpRequestDispatcher(String url, String method, byte[] postData) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.postData = postData;
    }

    public HttpRequestDispatcher(String url, String method) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
    }

    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need the `run()` method to return a `ByteArrayOutputStream` or a `String`. However, because it is in the `run()` method of the `Thread`, I cannot set the return type of the method to a  `ByteArrayOutputStream` or a `String`.

The `HttpRequestDispatcher` class is called inside of a class called OAuth.java.

How can I get around this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several solutions to this problem:

- Use an data structure external to the Thread. Pass the object in your constructor and update it, when your Thread is about to finish.
- Use a callback method. When your Thread finishes, call the callback.
- Make use of a [`java.util.concurrent.Future`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) (Java >= 1.5):

  > A Future represents the result of an asynchronous computation. Methods are provided to check if the computation is complete, to wait for its completion, and to retrieve the result of the computation.

Comment: With the callback method approach: The Thread will finish when the HttpRequest succeeds or fails. So let's say that I have two methods: requestSucceeded and requestFailed. The thread will call either one of those methods, depending on its result. My one question from there is how can I return the results of requestSucceeded or requestFailed back to the original method in OAuth.java which originally started the Thread? Thanks!

Comment: You could, e.g., define your callbacks in OAuth.java. Pass the OAuth object down to the Thread. Then, depending on the result, call the appropriate callback. The callback function could accept 'the sender' as one of the parameters, if you need to dispatch multiple Threads to different actions. That's just an idea ..

Answer (score 8):

Let it implement [`Callable<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of `Thread` or `Runnable`. Here `T` must represent the type of the result. Use [`ExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to execute it. It will return the result in flavor of a [`Future<V>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with `String` as `T`, just copy'n'paste'n'run it.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2300433;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task());
        System.out.println(future.get()); // Prints "result" after 2 secs.

        // Or if you have multiple tasks.
        // List<Future<String>> futures = executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(new Task()));
        // for (Future<String> future : futures) {
        //     System.out.println(future.get());
        // }

        executor.shutdown(); // Important!
    }
}

class Task implements Callable<String> {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return "result";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm planning to try out this approach. If you look at my comment on the below post, you will see that there are two cases in which the Thread will finish...it will succeed and return a ByteArrayOutputStream, or it will fail and return a stream. Is this a good method for accepting different types of objects? I am looking for versatility - there are going to be a lot of different classes using this HttpRequestDispatcher

Comment: Make it abstract and name it `HttpResponse`. It will become more straightforward.

Comment: I used that, and it worked fine for returning the result. Except that executor.shutdown didnt helped me with concurrent calls. I get an error of  "Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". In my call() method, I run a process that calls an exe and then I copy the a bytearray from that process and return it. Any ideas?